# How to use appium inspector with browserstack? Error: Failed to create session

Tags: appium-android, browserstack, appium-inspector

I'm trying to connect appium-inspector with browserstack but I'm getting this mistake:

Failed to create session. [browserstack.local] is set to true but local testing through BrowserStack is not connected. To resolve the issue or to get more info visit - https://www.browserstack.com/question/779

I looked it up internet but I couldn't fix it, my credentials are correct, so I don't know what is the problem, I even tried running bowserstack using cmd, but it didn't work.[image]

Connect appium-inspector with browserstack

Answer (score 0):

please visit the below page to get more details on how to use Appium inspector
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop

Regarding the error browserstack.local is true , but browserstack local is not connected, Please refer to the below page
https://www.browserstack.com/question/39484